# including predefined buttons from the footer in the Bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've used bootstrap to make the header and the footer so it will be responsive. When I resize the app buttons will have a collapse effect. But for the footer buttons I want something different. I want them to pop out in a popover effect. Like the ones on twitter. But I don't know how to include already created buttons from the footer in the popover. 
Hope you guys understand something from my poor explanations :)

```js
$(function (){
  $("[data-toggle = 'popover']").popover();
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 2000px;
}

#navbar-main {
    background: #017f55;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 0;
}
#title {
    color:#000;
    font-size: 43px;
    top:7px;
}

#select {
    color:#000;
    height:30px;
}
#nav-footer {
    background: #017f55;
    display:inline;
    text-align: right;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.footer-buttons {
    display:inline;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background-color: #017f55;
}
.icon-bar{
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
#footer-navbar {
    border-color: #000;
}
.footer-buttons {
    background-color: #017f55;
}
#footer-button {
    border:1px solid #333
}
#footer-button:hover {
    background-color: #333;
}
#footer-button:active {
    background-color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Code Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">


    </head>
    <body>
        <nav id="navbar-main" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <img src="images/test_logo.png">
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav center">
                <li><a href="#index" id="title">Code Test</a></li>
                <li><a>
                    <select id="select">
                        <option value="English">English</option>
                        <option value="Devanagari">Devanagari</option>
                    </select>
                </a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div>
        </nav>


        <nav id="nav-footer" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
            <div id="footer" class="container2">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button id="footer-button" type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="popover" data-target="#footer-navbar"  >
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div id="footer-navbar" class="navbar-inner navbar-content-center collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <button class="btn footer-buttons">About</p>
                    <button class="btn footer-buttons">Feedback</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by activating `html` option of the bootstrap popover, and by setting the content dynamically using `content` property, as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("[data-toggle = 'popover']").popover({
      html: 'true',
      content : '<button class="btn footer-buttons">About</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
          '<button class="btn footer-buttons">Feedback</button>'
   });
});
```

You can also dynamically read the buttons or any other html from your html markup and insert it into popover, as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("[data-toggle = 'popover']").popover({
      html: 'true',
      content : $("#footer-navbar").html()
   });
});
```

I just slightly changed your html markup where you did not close `button` tag properly. Check out a working example in [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/jWempM?editors=1010)

Comment: does it answer your question? If so, please accept the answer

Comment: just one more question to you :) Is ther any option tu change the buttons background on hover?

Comment: yes, you can have new css class with your desired styles. Then you can add it to the "content" stuff. It only works for the first approach though